# Rescaling icon made in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, brackets, tikzscale

A few days ago, I posted here about my tikz picture as an icon. So, you helped me and it worked. But now, I have some problem. I would like it to be rescaled so I could use it with command `\bracket{}{}`. Unfortunantely, when I use it as I declared it's so small, when I use it in this command. Maybe anybody could help and tell me how to rescale it to use with this command? Right now, it is scaled to the X letter. Here's my script of this icon:

```
\usepackage{tikz, scalerel} 


\def\icon{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture} 
      \draw[<->, line width=1pt]  (-.4,0) -- (.4,0); 
      \draw[<->, line width=1pt]  (0,-.4) -- (0,.4);
      \draw[<->, line width=1pt]  ({-.4*sin(45)},{-.4*cos(45)})  -- ({.4*sin(45)},{.4*cos(45)});
      \draw[<->, line width=1pt]  ({-.4*sin(45)},{.4*cos(45)})  -- ({.4*sin(45)}, {-.4*cos(45)});
\end{tikzpicture}}{X}}
```

Comment: Hay you tried  some  like `\scalebox{.5}{your-tikz-picture}` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mysymb[1][1]{%
\def\myscale{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[<->, line width={\myscale*1pt}]  ({-.4*\myscale},0) -- ({.4*\myscale},0); 
      \draw[<->, line width={1pt*\myscale}]  (0,{-.4*\myscale}) -- ({0,.4*\myscale});
      \draw[<->, line width={1pt*\myscale}]  ({-.4*sin(45)*\myscale},{-.4*cos(45)*\myscale})  -- ({.4*sin(45)*\myscale},{.4*cos(45)*\myscale});
      \draw[<->, line width=1pt*\myscale]  ({-.4*sin(45)*\myscale},{.4*cos(45)*\myscale})  -- ({.4*sin(45)*\myscale}, {-.4*cos(45)*\myscale});
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newsavebox{\myboxA}
\newsavebox{\myboxB}

\newcommand{\findmyscale}[1]{%
\savebox\myboxA{\hbox{#1}}%
\savebox\myboxB{\hbox{\mysymb}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\mysc{\the\wd\myboxA/\the\wd\myboxB}%
\xdef\mscale{\mysc}%
}



\begin{document}
X\mysymb X
\findmyscale{X}
X\mysymb[\mscale]X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what does this #1 do in \def\myscale{#1} and next to \findmyscale? And this line \pgfmathsetmacro\mysc{\the\wd\myboxA/\the\wd\myboxB}. 

Thanks

Comment: #1 is the first (optional) argument of the command in the first case and the mandatory argument of the command \findmyscale that will be used to calculate the width of both this argument (X here) and the original graph's width ... The \pgfmathsetmacro is used for the division of these two widths in order to find tha appropriate scaling factor that will be passed as #1 argument in the \mysymb command just after this calculation.